# In BizTalk 2013 R2, how to create response schema of web api as I need this response in BizTalk orchestration to update some tables in database

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

In BizTalk 2013 R2, I want to POST JSON request/string to web API. I used WCF-Web Http adapter and JSON decoder/encoder pipeline to create a JSON request. But I am unable to find how to create response schema as I need this response in BizTalk orchestration to update some tables in database. Have anyone worked on it?

Comment: please write down what you've tried so far (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @bibi - I have the json file hence created schema using json wizard in biztalk 2013 r2,created a send pipeline and used json encoder before sending the request, created an orchestration to send the req to web api,deployed application and created send port using wcf-webhttp adapter, configured url, mentioned POST verb, mentioned content type as appication/json, When I ran the application, I am getting the error : verify document schema specification. Api is sending some status code, how i do receive this in schema as I need this response code and the message for further processing.

Comment: Please add further details to the question by using the edit link underneath the question rather than in comments.   For starters you probably will want to set your receive pipeline to pass thru so you can capture the response message to investigate.  Add that to the question  as well

Comment: Option 1: Add a (file) sendport with a fillter that picks up the response from your webservice port (use sendport id to match). That will dump the web service responses 'as-is' and allow some more debugging. 
Option 2: Fire up fiddler (or the likes) and see the HTTP traffic in between the web service and biztalk.

Comment: Is your Send port a request response port?   What pipeline components do you have on the inbound?   Regarding the HTTP Status code, see this article http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16625.biztalk-server-rest-services-error-handling.aspx?goback=%2Egmr_53234  However that should really be a separate question

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments.

1. Capture the JSON response by having your inbound pipeline initially set the PassThru
2. Have a Send Port subscribing to the response on the send port and write it to a file
3. Use the JSON wizard to create a schema from the response file.
4. Deploy the response schema to BizTalk
5. Change the inbound pipeline to a custom pipeline with the JSON Decoder.

To Capture the HTTP Status from the REST Service see this article [BizTalk Server: REST Services Error Handling](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16625.biztalk-server-rest-services-error-handling.aspx?goback=%2Egmr_53234).  Which involves having the create a custom service behavior to capture the HTTP Status and inject it into the message context property.